# New CSS featured tags change text colour when visited

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The CSS tags for featured tags, such as [status-bydesign](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) and [featured](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured), when actually rendered in the page (instead of in a post body like that), have different text colours depending on whether they're visited or unvisited. Here's a screenshot with a visited link (top) and an unvisited one (bottom):

[image: Screenshot of the list of tags sidebar from Meta, showing two red featured tags, one with white text and one with hard-to-read grey text]

I'm pretty sure the gray visited-text is unintentional, so I'm submitting it as a bug.

Comment: Yep, looks like a duplicate.